How to access child id in for loop from parent in Slint UI Rust
I'm trying to access the function in a child element from the parent in Slint UI with something like this, but unfortunately I get an error that I cannot access id "Child". Any ideas how else I could trigger the child function from the parent?
import {Palette, Button, VerticalBox , LineEdit, StandardListView, GroupBox, StandardTableView, ListView, CheckBox} from "std-widgets.slint";

export component AppWindow inherits Window {
    VerticalLayout {
        Button {
            text: "parent";
            clicked => { Child.test(); }
        }
        ListView {
            for i in 50 : Child := HorizontalLayout{
                function test() {
                    Child.height = 0px;
                }
                Button {
                    text: "child";
                    clicked => { Child.test(); }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I've also tried using states, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to call a function from states. I got pretty close to what I was looking for this way, but I need it to be triggered once and not on or off.

so you're making 50 Child objects, each with a function test(). which of those 50 functions is supposed to be called when the parent button is pushed?
